# Test Garry's Mod Gamemode without portforwarding server

Tags: garrys-mod

I was trying to make my game on Unreal, but since I am not a one man gaming studio I decided to make it on Garry's Mod since nearly everything I need is already there and just needs the logic. I'm looking at some of the tutorials on getting started with making a gamemode, but they start off with you creating a server. I am on university internet and do not have access to port forwarding. Is there some other way for me to test my gamemode, preferably locally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out port forwarding is only needed if you are going to have other people connect to your server. You can connect to your own just fine if you are on the same machine, no port forwarding needed. I will test LAN soon.